# Wordpress social media feather plugin not returning the right featured image when shared in facebook and other social sites

Tags: facebook, wordpress

**This is my post featured image.**

[image]

**This is my post entitled "First post" with social icons at the bottom for sharing using social media feather plugin**

[image]

**This is what shows up when I clicked the facebook button**

[image]

The image above shows that it doesn't return the right image set as featured image for the first post to be shared in facebook. I also encountered the same problem using WP Social Sharing. Can anybody help me solve this please. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have the OpenGraph tags on your website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook, and other platforms that allow social sharing (LinkedIn, Twitter, G+, etc), all use a protocol called [OpenGraph](http://ogp.me/).

In it's simplest form, OpenGraph is a series of meta tags placed on a web page that describe that page.  Common tags include a title of the page, description, image and a category.  It is this OpenGraph image that Facebook uses in it's preview for the social share.

The tag itself is called `og:image`, and Facebook suggest it is at least `1200x630` pixels, although they will still use the image if it is less than that.  As a side note for anyone viewing this thread and having the same issue with Facebook apps - you'll need to serve the image over HTTPS for that, something you don't need to do in this case.

I would suggest viewing the source of your page and finding the OpenGraph tags.  If none are present (very possible) then Facebook is just doing it's best based on what it sees on the page.  You can remedy this by adding your own tags, or using one of the many OpenGraph plugins available for WordPress.

More information on [Facebook's best practices for social sharing are available](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices).

Comment: I was able to used the WP open graph plugin for my site. However, it doesn't still render the right image or featured image for the particular post. I checked the page source and it already contains open graph tags and a correct path for the featured image but not the right image when showed in facebook share page. <meta property="og:image" content="http://dticaraga.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/commodities2.jpg" /> this is the right path of the featured image but ain't able to show it in the shared page instead a different image is placed.

Comment: But it renders the right featured image using google plus. Are there things I need to set up for this to work using facebook share?

Comment: You should include a protocol (`http://`), so the link should be `http://dticaraga.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/commodities2.jpg`, you also have a semi-colon in there, which may be throwing the Facebook parser off - it certainly confuses StackOverflow's link regexp which automagically turns URLs into hyperlinks